# What structure/grammar point is this?

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction, sentence-structure, structure, phrase-structure

> "Several disturbing dreams had given me a restless night, though I could only remember them vaguely. In one dream I recall shouting at someone and being involved in a fight. There was also something about an animal, but what it was I couldn't recollect."

If I were the writer of this text, I would say "I couldn't recollect what it was" instead of "what it was I couldn't recollect", although I'm aware that both structures are correct. However, I would like to know the name of the first structure and its usage (is it used for emphasis?).

Comment: It is a form of emphasis to invert the order and place the object first.

Comment: Is this from Dr Jekel and Mr Hyde or some similar novel?

Comment: By this,the writer is trying to direct our focus to the object, not of the recollection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's [topicalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topicalization):

> ... a mechanism of syntax that establishes an expression as the sentence or clause topic by having it appear at the front of the sentence or clause (as opposed to in a canonical position further to the right).

Now that you know what name the phenomenon goes by, hopefully you can find what you need.

Comment: So you think there's a form of inversion here, meaning that the grammatical subject is "a restless night"?

Comment: @BillJ No, the first two sentences in the example are unrelated to the phenomenon. The question is why it's "what it was I couldn't recollect", with the object "what it was" in front of the subject and verb "I couldn't recollect", rather than the expected "I couldn't recollect what it was" SVO order. And the answer is that we front the object, creating OSV order, to topicalize it.